# How to update remote file?

Tags: command-line

I need to update the contents of a file on a remote host from my local Linux machine. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you need to update? What content? How do you connect to the remote server? The more information you give, the likelier it is someone will be able to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

- ssh + local edit
- ftp
- scp
- vnc
- emacs using tramp via some protocol
- etc...

All depends on what you have on the server and what you can install.
Also, the size of the file may be worth considering.

Comment: @Sukminder would do as well, but I was hoping he had rights on that server, at least :)

Comment: Print out the data, walk to the server's location, log on to the server, copy the data into the file :).

Comment: @terdon: you laugh, but I once had the case of an office assistant in an engineering school who was asking how to import some data into an excel file... we couldn't figure out what she was doing wrong until we realized she was asking about getting data from a *printout* into the spreadsheet. Stupid assumption on our part, probably... (the original data came from a PDF file, so she printed it out as she couldn't copy paste it into excel correctly).